# How to avoid "source lines moving nausea" when opening a source with the new IntelliJ UI? Few seconds after opening, lines are moving bottom and right

Tags: intellij-idea

Since I switched to the new IntelliJ UI, I got nausea.

When I open a Java source, it is displayed with its lines all black, without any language formatting.
It is not really usable, in fact... I have to wait and 0.5 to 1.5 seconds after that.

And then I see, in the space of tens of seconds, many moves:

- IntelliJ discovers that it's a Java source: source formatting and colors are coming, and the lines goes down, due to the bold applied,
- But also IntelliJ changes the interlining of the source, putting temporary a line spacing between, for example, a class and its javadoc, and then discovering that this line doesn't exit and remove it from display.
- The sidebar at the left of the source with the signs: Override, Service, Navigate to dependencies, breakpoints... start being filled, which enlarge it twice large it is, and this shift the source to the right.

With moves from the top to down,
and the left to the right,
each source opened gives sea sick.

Is it possible to ask *IntelliJ*
to wait before displaying a source:

- that it fully understands it
- that it is really ready to display it?

(maybe it means asking *IntelliJ* to display a source only after having ran all its related inspections on it, and not before, if it the condition to stop disordered moves?)